# React Redux UI not updating after delete action

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

**Description:**

I'm building a React application using Redux Toolkit to manage state. I have a component `ItemsReadView` that displays a list of items and allows users to delete items using a Redux action. However, after the delete action is dispatched, the UI doesn't update immediately. The item is only removed from the UI after a page reload.

I've followed the suggestions provided from different sources and reviewed my code carefully, but I'm still facing this issue. Here's what I've tried so far:

- Verified the delete action is being dispatched and the Redux state is being updated correctly.
- Checked that the component should automatically rerender when the state changes.
- Ensured there are no errors shown in the console or network tab.

**Code Snippets:**

1. **Redux Action and Reducer:**

   **itemsSlice.js**

```
export const deleteItemActionCreator = createAsyncThunk(
  "items/deleteItemActionCreator",
  async (id, { rejectWithValue }) => {
    try {
      const res = await axios.delete(`${backendURL}/items/${id}`);
      return res.data;
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return rejectWithValue(err.response?.data);
    }
  }
);
```

```
      .addCase(deleteItemActionCreator.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        const itemsAfterDelete = state.items.filter(
          (item) => item.id !== action.payload.id
        );
        state.items = itemsAfterDelete;
        state.createItemStatus = "";
        state.createItemError = "";
        state.readItemsStatus = "";
        state.readItemsError = "";
        state.updateItemStatus = "";
        state.updateItemError = "";
        state.deleteItemStatus = "success";
        state.deleteItemError = "";
      })
```

2. **Component Code:**

   **ItemsReadView.js**

```
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(readItemsActionCreator());
  }, [dispatch]);
  const { items } = useSelector((state) => state.itemsState);
```

```
  const handleDelete = (id) => {
    dispatch(deleteItemActionCreator(id));
  };
```

```
          <TableBody>
            {items.map((item) => (
              <TableRow key={item.id}>
                <TableCell> {item.name} </TableCell>
                <TableCell> {item.price} </TableCell>
                <TableCell align="center">
                  <ButtonGroup size="small">
                    <Button
                      color="info"
                      onClick={() => handleOpenItemUpdateView(item)}
                    >
                      Update
                    </Button>
                    <Button color="error" onClick={() => handleDelete(item.id)}>
                      Delete
                    </Button>
                  </ButtonGroup>
                </TableCell>
              </TableRow>
            ))}
          </TableBody>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that when I sent a delete request to the server, the server was responding with an empty object, as expected. However, this empty object was being set as the `action.payload` in my Redux action. Since this object had no `id` or any other data, my filtering logic based on the `id` was not working correctly, resulting in no updates to the UI.

To resolve this issue, I made the following changes:

In my `deleteItemActionCreator`, I removed the assignment of the server response to `res` and instead returned the `id` of the item being deleted as the payload. This ensured that the payload contained a valid `id` for filtering.

```
export const deleteItemActionCreator = createAsyncThunk(
  "items/deleteItemActionCreator",
  async (id, { rejectWithValue }) => {
    try {
      await axios.delete(`${backendURL}/items/${id}`);
      return id; // Return the id as payload
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return rejectWithValue(err.response?.data);
    }
  }
);
```

In my reducer, I updated the filtering logic to use the `action.payload` (which now contains the valid `id`) to filter out the deleted item from the state.

```
.addCase(deleteItemActionCreator.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
  const itemsAfterDelete = state.items.filter(
    (item) => item.id !== action.payload
  );
  // Update the state with filtered items
})
```

By making these changes, I ensured that the filtering logic correctly identified the item to be deleted and updated the UI without needing to manually refresh the page.